# Iterating through pairs of letters in a text file and counting occurrences

Tags: python

I have a text file, called test.txt. In this text file, the following information is found:

```
AATA
ATTA
TAAT
TATA
```

I now want to look at pairs of letters that occur across all four segments of letters and count the occurrences of all possible pairs of letters. (there are 4 possible combinations: AA, AT, TA, TT). I first want to do that for position 1 (I call this x = 1), where the pairs would be AA, AT, TA, TA. I then want to compute the percentage of occurrences of each possible combination, to get column 1 of a 3-column matrix. (Here, I would find 1 occurrence of AA, 1 occurrence of AT, and 2 occurrences of TA. The percentages for x = 1 would thus be:

```
p_AA = 25, p_AT = 25, p_TA = 50, p_TT = 0
```

I then want to move to position 2 (x = 2), where the pairs would be AT, TT, AA, AT. I would again calculate the percentages:

```
p_AA = 25, p_AT = 50, p_TA = 0, p_TT = 25
```

Finally, I would move to position 3 (x = 3), to get the pairs TA, TA, AT, TA and again calculate the percentages:

```
p_AA = 0, p_AT = 25, p_TA = 75, p_TT = 0
```

To summarize all these results, I would like to make a list, where the column is x and the rows are the individual percentages. I would expect a result like this:

```
25, 25, 0
25, 50, 25
50, 0, 75
0, 25, 0
```

However, I have problems reading and counting two letters per iteration and then placing them correctly into this matrix.

I have the following code:

```
with open("Test.txt", "r") as f1: lines = f1.readlines()
count_lines = len(content)

with open("Test.txt", "r") as f2: letters = f2.read()
count_letters = int((len(letters) - count_lines) / count_lines)

i = 0
j = 1

list = []

for x in range(1, count_letters):
    AA = 0
    AT = 0
    TA = 0
    TT = 0
   
    for line in content:
        if line[i] == "A" and line[j] == "A": AA = AA + 1
        if line[i] == "A" and line[j] == "T": AT = AT + 1
        if line[i] == "T" and line[j] == "A": TA = TA + 1
        if line[i] == "T" and line[j] == "T": TT = TT + 1
    sum = count_lines
    p_AA = 100*AA/sum
    p_AT = 100*AT/sum
    p_TA = 100*TA/sum
    p_TT = 100*TT/sum

    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
```

This seems too cumbersome and I don't manage to get the matrix with the dimensions as mentioned, no matter what I try.

Comment: In the second `open` you open as `f1` but you do an `f2.read()`, that doesn't look right. Also, you do `len(content)` while you're actually reading `lines`. I don't think this is working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all of your pairs would be present in your data set at least once in any position of any of the inputs, you can just use counters then construct a pandas dataframe, transpose it and do the math on it.

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['AATA','ATTA','TAAT','TATA']

o = []
for i, x in enumerate(range(2,5)):
    o.append(Counter([e[i:x] for e in l]))
    
    
df = pd.DataFrame(o)

((df.T/4)*100).fillna(0).values.tolist()
```

Output

```
[[25.0, 25.0, 0.0], [25.0, 50.0, 25.0], [50.0, 0.0, 75.0], [0.0, 25.0, 0.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary.  This would solve the problem, you have to create a counter for each pair. This is just for the pairing problem.

```
def count_pairs(pairs, content):
    for i in range(len(content)-1):
        if content[i] == content[i+1]:
            key = "{}{}".format(content[i].upper(), content[i].upper())
            if key in pairs:
                pairs[key] += 1
            else:
                pairs[key] = 1

pairs = dict()
count_pairs(pairs, content)
```